# Are Zariski connected and closed semisimple subgroups of semisimple and simply connected algebraic groups again simply connected?

Tags: algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a semisimple and simply connected linear algebraic group over $\mathbb{C}$.
Let $H$ be a connected, Zariski closed and semisimple linear algebraic $\mathbb{Q}$-subgroup of $G$.

Is $H$ a simply connected linear algebraic group?

Here "simply connected" means every central isogeny to $G$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: No. $H$ need not be simply connected

Comment: @Amir: Your definition of "simply connected" is too narrow for this kind of question, which makes sense and has a similar easy answer over any algebraically closed field.    Aside from that, there are already questions on MO which cover similar ground in a more refined style.   Search for "simply connected" [algebraic-groups].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Venkataramana says, the answer is no. In fact, every linear algebraic $\mathbb{Q}$-group $H$, whether simply connected or not, is (isomorphic to) a Zariski closed $\mathbb{Q}$-subgroup of some $SL_n$ (which is semisimple and simply connected). (By definition of being an algebraic group, $H$ is a Zariski closed $\mathbb{Q}$-subgroup of $GL_k$, for some $k$. Furthermore, it is well known that $GL_k$ can be embedded as a Zariski-closed $\mathbb{Q}$-subgroup of $SL_{k+1}$.)